# Incomplete Implementation on xcode4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, xcode4

I am just new on Objective-C , well i have not get in to cocoa touch library yet, but i am try to follow Objective-C book and write some classes for get in more practice .

I have a error in Implementation statement , could you tell me which part that i made mistake ?

```
#import "getterSetter.h"

@implementation getterSetter

@synthesize airportName;

- (char) print : (char) name 
{
    return name;
}

- (int) zip : (int) zipair
{
    return zipair;
}
@end


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char *airportName;
    getterSetter *airport = [[getterSetter alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"Please enter the airport name:\n");
    scanf("%c",&airportName);

    NSLog(@"Please enter the airport name:\n");
    scanf("%c",&airportName);    

    NSLog(@"Your Airport Name is :\n");
    [airport print:*airportName];
}
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface getterSetter : NSObject
{
    char *airportName;
    int zipCode;
    char *airportCityName;
}

- (char) print : (char) name;

- (int) zip;

@property char *airportName;

@end
```

Comment: Your question is way too vague

Comment: Xcode says me that , Incomplete Implementation on Line 2 ,  which indicate @implementation construction

Comment: Include such vital information in the question.

Comment: Which statement that i don't need semicolon? coz I didnt use when i indicate _@implementation nor _@interface ....

Comment: I was referring to `@implementation`

Comment: You should provide more specifics. If you say "I have an error" then provide the exact text of the error Xcode is giving to you. Saying you have an error isn't enough for us, you need to give us all the details you can.

Comment: Your class names should always start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: I know it should be always in uppercase but Compiler still execute as success  ? And Carl Veazey , my problem has solved by Martin R. thanks for your interest ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In getterSetter.h, you declare a method

```
- (int) zip;
```

but in the .m file you implement

```
- (int) zip : (int) zipair
```

That is a different method, therefore the compiler complains about the missing implementation of `- (int) zip`.

Comment: thank you so much :) I just getting blind while i am modifying constructors :/ , That  fixed code !